# Moving responsive element - clone or duplicate

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, clone, enquire.js

I have an element and as part of the responsive design it has to move to a different section on my page.

As I see it I have 2 solutions

(i) have a duplicate element and use visibility in css.

(ii) use enquire.js and move the element.

Option 1 is the easier but is there a problem having duplicate markup to achieve this task? I am sure someone will tel me if an element has to move the deisgn is flawed, however I did not design the site. Any thoughts on best practice would be appreciated. On a really clean solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think that option one is better. However, it depends on the type of elements you want to move. I know how you could do it either way. If possible please post the code that you are looking move/hide/show and I will likely be able to write some code for you. I'm on the phone right now.

Comment: Thanks it's nothing that exciting just a div with a p tag. I can do the techy bit, it's more best practice for seo and unnecessarily bloating the  html, I was interested in what people do rather than how they do it.